# FactoryGirl Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I have a pretty basic rails app that I'm working on.

Parts are in certain states (state_id), they are created by a user (user_id) and have an associated type with them (type_id).

Trying to create a factory for part, I have:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :part do
    name "blah"
    association :state_id, factory: :state
    association :user_id, factory: :user
    association :techtype_id, factory: :techtype
  end

  factory :state do
    name "blah"
  end

  factory :user do
    login "blah"
  end

  factory :techtype do
    name "blah"
    example "bleh"
  end
end
```

Yet FactoryGirl.create(:part) doesn't seem to work:

```
2.0.0p353 :001 > part = FactoryGirl.create(:part)
[SQL insert for State, User, and Techtype outputs here and succeeds, then...]
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: 
   State can't be blank, Techtype can't be blank, User can't be blank
```

I've tried removing the `_id` attribute (i.e. `association :state, factory: :state`) but that doesnt work either, I just get a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'state=' for #<Part:0x007fa3e8e798a0>`. I've also just tried using the short form association (i.e. `state` instead of `association :state_id, factory: :state`) but I get the same `NoMethodError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model should look like this

```
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :techtype
end
```

And your factory like this

```
 factory :part do
    name "blah"
    association :state
    association :user
    association :techtype
  end
```

Comment: Turns out that after staring at my code, I had left out the belongs_to attributes in my Part class. First time doing associations with ActiveRecord, so I missed that. Thanks

Comment: For newer factory_girl syntax:
 `factory :part do
    name "blah"
    state
    user
    techtype
  end`
Assuming you have factories with names state, user, and techtype. FactoryGirl will know how to do the rest.